# Jar as a Service in RHEL 8.2 - Not Starting

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, systemd

I have a spring boot uber jar that I need to run as a service in RHEL 8.2 environment.

The service file created in /etc/systemd/system/myapp.service is as simple as this:

```
[Unit]
Description=myapp

[Service]
User=appuser
WorkingDirectory=/home/appuser 
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -Xmx256m -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=test /home/appuser/myapp.jar 
SuccessExitStatus=143
TimeoutStopSec=10
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now when I try to start the service and check the status using the below commands I get the below error:

```
[root@myappdev01 /etc/systemd/system]# sudo systemctl status myapp
myapp.service - myapp
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/myapp.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-09-11 23:48:26 +04; 5s ago
  Process: 273497 ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=test /home/appuser/myapp.jar (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 273497 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 11 23:48:26 myappdev01.server systemd[1]: myapp.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 11 23:48:26 myappdev01.server systemd[1]: myapp.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

`journatlctl -u myapp.service` also doesn't help much.

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: Try running the command "/usr/bin/java -Xmx256m -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=test /home/appuser/myapp.jar" (or whatever it is now) at the shell prompt.  Does it work?

Comment: yes, that's the funny part. The command works when it is run at the shell.

Comment: Could it be SELinux?  Could it be permissions on something?

Comment: nothing tht is in my knowledge. Any idea what i can try ?

Comment: Do you know if SELinux is enabled / enforcing on your machine?  (I think it is "on" by default on RHEL.)

Comment: it's in Permissive mode.

Comment: Not that then.  What happens if you 1) `su appuser`, 2) `cd /home/appuser`, 3) Run the command.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221529/discussion-between-tokyo-and-stephen-c).

Answer (score 1):

The jar you're using needs to come directly after the `-jar` flag:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -Xmx256m -Dspring.profiles.active=test -jar /home/appuser/myapp.jar
```